# Does scipy.interpolate.interp1d have problems with decimal values leading the x values?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to use *interp1d()* from scipy to interpolate some data, but I keep hitting an out or range error. After hours of Googling, I now know that x values not in increasing order will cause the same error I'm getting but I've already made sure that's not the problem. As far as I can tell, it looks like *interp1d()* doesn't like decimals in the first value. Am I missing something?

**A simplified version of my problem:**

The following runs just fine.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

interp1d(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
         np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]), kind='cubic')(np.linspace(1, 6, num=40))
```

But, this:

```
interp1d(np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6]),
     np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]), kind='cubic')(np.linspace(1, 6, num=40))
```

Returns:

> ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range.

But, this works just fine.

```
interp1d(np.array([1.0, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6]),
         np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]), kind='cubic')(np.linspace(1, 6, num=40))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`inter1d` returns a function which allows you to interpolate *within the domain of the data*. When you use

```
interp1d(np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6]),
     np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]), kind='cubic')(np.linspace(1, 6, num=40))
```

the domain of the data is the interval `[1.1, 6.6]`, the minimum to maximum values of the `x-values`.

Since `1` is in `np.linspace(1, 6, num=40)` and 1 lies outside `[1.1, 6.6]`, `interp1d` raises

```
ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range.
```

when you try to interpolate the data at the `x-values` `np.linspace(1, 6, num=40)`.

When you change the `x-values` of the data to

```
np.array([1.0, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6])
```

then the domain of the data is expanded to `[1.0, 6.6]`, which now includes `1`. Hence, interpolating at `np.linspace(1, 6, num=40)` now works.

Comment: Thank you very much. It took my dense brain a few passes to get it, but I realized from your explanation that I had it backwards. I was trying to fit the wrong range inside of the other. I thought the old x values needed to fit within the range produced by linspace(), not the other way around.