# `ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.` - what other reasons than not ascending values?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I receive this error in scipy interp1d function. Normally, this error would be generated if the x was not monotonically increasing.

```
import scipy.interpolate as spi
def refine(coarsex,coarsey,step):
    finex = np.arange(min(coarsex),max(coarsex)+step,step)
    intfunc = spi.interp1d(coarsex, coarsey,axis=0)
    finey = intfunc(finex)
    return finex, finey

for num, tfile in enumerate(files):
    tfile = tfile.dropna(how='any')
    x = np.array(tfile['col1'])
    y = np.array(tfile['col2'])
    finex, finey = refine(x,y,0.01)
```

The code is correct, because it successfully worked on 6 data files and threw the error for the 7th. So there must be something wrong with the data. But as far as I can tell, the data increase all the way down.
I am sorry for not providing an example, because I am not able to reproduce the error on an example.

There are two things that could help me:

1. Some brainstorming - if the data are indeed monotonically
   increasing, what else could produce this error? Another hint,
   regarding the decimals, could be in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30244888/5553319), but I think
   my solution (the min and max of x) is robust enough to avoid it. Or
   isn't it?
2. Is it possible (how?) to return the value of x_new and
   it's index when throwing the `ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.` so that I could actually see where in the
   file is the problem?

**UPDATE**

So the problem is that, for some reason, `max(finex)` is larger than `max(coarsex)` (one is .x39 and the other is .x4). I hoped rounding the original values to 2 significant digits would solve the problem, but it didn't, it displays fewer digits but still counts with the undisplayed. What can I do about it?

Comment: I would focus on the min/max of `finex` compared to the range of `coarsex`.  The message tells me that some value of `finex` larger than any value of `coarsex`, in a region that would require extrapolation.

Comment: how could a value of `finex` be larger than that of `coarsex` if it is stated that it should only range to the maximum value of `coarsex`? Oh I see, I guess it could happen if the `step` is larger than the difference between the maximum and the second maximum value... No, wait, it can't, because the step is `step`!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you are running Scipy v. 0.17.0 or newer, then you can [pass `fill_value='extrapolate'` to `spi.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html), and it will extrapolate to accomadate these values of your's that lie outside the interpolation range.  So define your interpolation function like so:

`intfunc = spi.interp1d(coarsex, coarsey,axis=0, fill_value="extrapolate")`

#### Be forewarned, however!

Depending on what your data looks like and the type on interpolation you are performing, the extrapolated values can be erroneous.  This is especially true if you have noisy or non-monotonic data.  In your case you might be ok because your x_new value is only *slighly* beyond your interpolation range.

Here's simple demonstration of how this feature can work nicely but also give erroneous results.

```
import scipy.interpolate as spi
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = x + np.random.randint(-1,1,100)/100
x_new = np.linspace(0,1.1,100)
intfunc = spi.interp1d(x,y,fill_value="extrapolate")
y_interp = intfunc(x_new)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x_new,y_interp,'r', label='interp/extrap')
plt.plot(x,y, 'b--', label='data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

So the interpolated portion (in red) worked well, but the extrapolated portion clearly fails to follow the otherwise linear trend in this data because of the noise.  So have some understanding of your data and proceed with caution.

Answer (score 4):

A quick test of your `finex` calc shows that it can (always?) gets into the extrapolation region.

```
In [124]: coarsex=np.random.rand(100)
In [125]: max(coarsex)
Out[125]: 0.97393109991816473
In [126]: step=.01;finex=np.arange(min(coarsex), max(coarsex)+step, step);(max(
     ...: finex),max(coarsex))
Out[126]: (0.98273730602114795, 0.97393109991816473)
In [127]: step=.001;finex=np.arange(min(coarsex), max(coarsex)+step, step);(max
     ...: (finex),max(coarsex))
Out[127]: (0.97473730602114794, 0.97393109991816473)
```

Again it is a quick test, and may be missing some critical step or value.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks, you are right, the problem lies somewhere in the 6th significant digit... `Min coarse, min fine, max coarse, max fine 261.4134814 261.4134814 524.9398314 524.9434814`. So I tried to round the values to 2 significant digits, but it still doesn't work (is it rounded only in display, but still counting with more digits? Am I really stuck on the thin ice of mysterious numbers of bits in a float?) ... how to get around?