# Python: How to resample a 3d curve given by points as spline in equal distances?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

Allow me to separate this to increasing difficulty questions:

---

**1.**

I have some 1d curve, given as a `(n,)` point array.

I would like to have it re-sampled `k` times, and have the results come from a cubic spline that passes through all points.

This can be done with [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html)

---

**2.**
The curve is given at non-same-interval samples as an array of shape `(n, 2)` where `(:, 0)` represents the sample time, and `(:, 1)` represent the sample values.

I want to re-sample the curve at k same-time-intervals.

How can this be done?

I thought i could do `t_sampler = interp1d(np.arange(0,k),arr[:, 0])` for the time, then `interp1d(t_sampler(np.arange(0,k)), arr[:, 1])`

Am I missing something with this?

---

**3.**

How can I re-sample the curve at equal **distance** intervals? (question 2 was equal **time** intervals)

---

**4.**

What if the curve is 3d given by an array of shape `(n, 4)`, where `(:,0)` are the (non uniform) sampling times, and the rest are the locations sampled?

---

Sorry for many-questionsin-single-question, they seemed too similar to open a new question for every one.

Comment: Did **2.** work for you? **3** - Did you try making a poly or interp1d swapping the x an y (time and distance) then do the same as **2.**?

Comment: Look at splprep for curves and distances along rhe curve

Comment: @wwii 2. gives me `"A value in x_new is below the interpolation "
                             "range."` on `interp1d(t_sampler(np.arange(0,k)), arr[:, 1])` and I have no Idea why

Comment: Possibly related: [`ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.` - ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429831/valueerror-a-value-in-x-new-is-above-the-interpolation-range-what-other-re) ...  without an [mcve] (emphasis on minimal, reproducible) it will be hard to help.

Comment: `Sorry for many-questionsin-single-question,` - one problem with asking multiple questions is that there may be SO Q&A's for one or more of them but there won't be an one that covers them all.  You should ask one at a time with a [mcve] and if appropriate some or all may get marked duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer; for 1 and 2 I would do this:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np

# dummy data
x = np.arange(-100,100,10)
y = x**2 + np.random.normal(0,1, len(x))

# interpolate:
f = interp1d(x,y, kind='cubic')

# resample at k intervals, with k = 100:
k = 100
# generate x axis:
xnew = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), k)

# call f on xnew to sample y values:
ynew = f(xnew)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(xnew, ynew)
```

Comment: This solves 1. For 2, I'm not so sure, because `interp1d` wants both x and y to be of the same length, thus can't interpolate sampled y  on xnew directly

Comment: I think I misunderstood 2 in that case. Would it be possible for you to share examples of the data?

Comment: It is I who didn't understand. this solves 1 and 2.